# Kohana или CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, kohana

Что лучше Kohana или CodeIgniter? Начал работать я на CodeIgniter, все понравилось, но увидел некие посты против CodeIgniter, пожалуйста, посоветуйте, что же начать учить? И почему, если можно.

Comment: С чем удобно с тем и работайте, что хотите то и учите, никого не слушайте :)

Comment: Мне бы хотелось профессионального совета)) Мне легче учиться когда спецы одобряют : )

Comment: ок - учите кохану, потому-что **codeigniter** уже не развивается

Comment: Хорошо, а из Yii и кохана, выбор каков?

Comment: Вот на этот вопрос точно ответить нельзя. В чем то лучше кохана, в чем то Yii. Лично мне больше импонирует kohana, просто мне она больше нравится, не более :)

Comment: Любой фреймворк можно дополнить, улучшить. Поэтому нет разницы особой. Лучше выбрать тот, с которым лучше ладишь и тот который легче для тебя. Мне лучше показался codeigniter, хотя говорят о нем, что он не развивается. Мой code-igniter развивается. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите соответствующее [**сравнение возможностей.**](http://rmcreative.ru/playground/php-frameworks/)

*Мне вообще, например, больше всех нравится [**Symfony.**](http://symfony.com/)*

---

И, разумеется, стоит все-таки тратить время на написание кода, нежели холиварное обсуждение возможностей фреймворков. Все современные `php` фреймворки так или иначе подойдут под ваши задачи, возьмите какой-либо с приятной документацией - и вперед.

Comment: У Коханы приятная документация. На английском )

Answer (score 0):

1) В простых проектах не нужно использовать ООП, а это ключевая особенность Kohana.

2) Kohana - это проект сообщества, а CodeIgniter - проект компании, которая на нём разработала - CMS ExpressionEngine 2.0 (в США много магазинов работают на нём), т.е. к CI подход серьезный чем любительский (хотя люди из сообщество Kohana - будут писать что я не прав).

3) CodeIgniter - теперь стал очень быстро развиваться, уже 3.0 версия релизная не за горами!
Посмотирте: [GitHub](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter) и [GetSparks](http://getsparks.org/)!

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какие цели изучения фреймворка... если хотите стать серьёзным и профессиональным программистом, тогда лучше по раньше начать принимать [PSR](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Standarty_kodirovaniya_PHP_PSR.html) стандарты кодирования и современные приёмы такие как "контейнер сервисов", а также использовать современные библиотеки такие как Twig и Doctrine... в общем в этом случае очевиден только один выбор - [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/).